# Paypal subscription payment without recurring process

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, braintree, subscription, recurring

I tried to create a payment process like prepaid services. If user enter credit card details in my site create a new profile (like recurring user profile) in paypal through Api. After the user used my services immediately charged the user using those profile credited in paypal.

My need stored the user credit details in paypal, payment trigger from my site. Using Rest API. Please suggest me which payment type i need to use in paypal.
[image]